# How do I run one of the Chart.JS examples locally via HTML?

Tags: chart.js

I tried many things sofar but it did not work, mostly trying to make one of the Chart.JS examples run locally on my Mac but the html chart wont show up. Every try leads to a blank html page.

I mostly tried utilizing the basic Chart.JS html chart as the framework then swapped in the mainframe code to the code that I wanted to use for the chart. I also did try a few modifications yet none of them work at all.

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Testing here</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
      
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
      
      <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
      
        // <block:actions:2>
        const actions = [
        {
            name: 'Randomize',
            handler(chart) {
            chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                dataset.data = Utils.numbers({count: chart.data.labels.length, min: -100, max: 100});
            });
            chart.update();
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Add Dataset',
            handler(chart) {
            const data = chart.data;
            const dsColor = Utils.namedColor(chart.data.datasets.length);
            const newDataset = {
                label: 'Dataset ' + (data.datasets.length + 1),
                backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(dsColor, 0.5),
                borderColor: dsColor,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: Utils.numbers({count: data.labels.length, min: -100, max: 100}),
            };
            chart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
            chart.update();
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Add Data',
            handler(chart) {
            const data = chart.data;
            if (data.datasets.length > 0) {
                data.labels = Utils.months({count: data.labels.length + 1});

                for (let index = 0; index < data.datasets.length; ++index) {
                data.datasets[index].data.push(Utils.rand(-100, 100));
                }

                chart.update();
            }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Remove Dataset',
            handler(chart) {
            chart.data.datasets.pop();
            chart.update();
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Remove Data',
            handler(chart) {
            chart.data.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

            chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                dataset.data.pop();
            });

            chart.update();
            }
        }
        ];
        // </block:actions>

        // <block:setup:1>
        const DATA_COUNT = 7;
        const NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: -100, max: 100};

        const labels = Utils.months({count: 7});
        const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
            {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
            borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
            backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.red, 0.5),
            order: 1
            },
            {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
            borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
            backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
            type: 'line',
            order: 0
            }
        ]
        };
        // </block:setup>

        // <block:config:0>
        const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Combined Line/Bar Chart'
            }
            }
        },
        };
        // </block:config>

module.exports = {
  actions: actions,
  config: config,
};

      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Am I doing anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems *(that I can see)*,

1. your code is using `Utils. ...`, but the javascript file is not loaded.
   **Solution:** replace the `Utils....` code or loadthe Javascript file for it
2. you are not adding the chart to the page.
   **Solution:**
   Add this code at the end of the script.

   ```
    new Chart(
        ctx,
        config
    );
   ```

**Here, a cleaned version of your demo, how it could work:**

1. I remove most "unneeded" code
2. the data is static all on the same height, but you can change this easily, by setting the property `data`

```js
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
      
    const labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    // create random Data
    const helpData1 = labels.map( _ => Math.random() * 100);
    const helpData2 = labels.map( _ => Math.random() * 100);
    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: helpData1,
            borderColor: '#ff0000',
            backgroundColor: '#ff000088',
            order: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data:  helpData2,
            borderColor: '#0000ff', 
            backgroundColor:'#0000ff88',
            type: 'line',
            order: 0
          }
      ]
    };
  
   const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: data,
      options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Combined Line/Bar Chart'
            }
          }
      },
    };
          
    new Chart(
        ctx,
        config
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div class="chart" style="height:184px">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: So its moreso of a code bloat issue then? I wonder if there's a way to add in multiple 'line's for the bar-line hybird chart?(Trying to do a SQL live-fetched Bar-Line hybrid chart but I do not know where to start even with Chart.JS as much as I love to try and solve it).

Also is there a way to set up my SQL server without having to do it locally? I got the account data but sofar I couldn't connect to the SQL server for some reason.

Comment: @EvaT more or less yes, much of the code is just to make the examples more interesting. Add multiple lines should be possible. (just checkout the example page https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/information.html, btw, if you change the code in the examples, and there are no errors, these changes are reflected, great for testing.)  if you want data you of the SQL server, you will have to use a scriptting/programming language (like php, c#, pyhton, nodejs,... ) to access the data, create some sort of website (but this is beyond the scope of chartjs).

Comment: Oh, that's the plan - Trying to connect to the SQL server just for the website but sofar I couldn't access the site at all. I feel I might have broke something along the way. (I'm using VS Code to connect to the main site, as to allow me to link it to Chart.JS and from there set it all up into a neat website. Too bad its my first time toying around with the code so I'm kinda stuck with alot of Trial and Error).

Comment: I almost forgot, I had to set this up in VS Code, since its the only editor I know best. I tried Node.JS but I wasn't sure how to edit code in Node.JS.

Comment: @EvaT Node.js is a programming "framework"  (based on javascript), not an editor. I also use only VSCode. You can write code in VSCode and just run it with node for example: `node app.js`

Comment: Oh, I never knew you could do that. Usually when I try to run the code, I run it directly through VS code and never via Node.JS. Is there any setup I would need to install onto Node(like move app.js to a specific Node.JS folder) before I can run it on Node?

My main plan was to run it on html(hence the hmtl code at the start), of which I tried to add the Chart.JS example code directly within the html code as to work. I feel like I missed a few steps but so far I am unsure which ones do I focus on.

Comment: Almost forgot - I was able to find an easier tutorial on how it works(Plan to add in a second scale to boot) but I am unsure if it'll work with the latest version of Chart.JS(4.0.1): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OIjC6yh94E